# "Undefined control sequence" error message

Tags: errors

While compiling, an error message "Undefined control sequence" for the fourth line below (starting with 1958*e.....). Any idea about the cause?

```
\begin{equation}
S = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
1280*Q^{0.46}*(1.43-0.26*\log{A}) & \mbox{if} & Q<2 in \\ 
1958*e^{-0.055}*Q*(1.43-0.26*\logA) & \mbox{if} & Q\geq2 in 
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The culprit is `\logA`. Replace it by `\log A`, i.e. add a space. But you really may want to have a look at some intro, and use e.g. `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` and `\text` instead of `\mbox` and so on.

Comment: the error message which you do not show highlights exactly which command is undefined

Comment: You have `\log{A}` and `\logA`: both should be `\log A` (no braces and a space).

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between

```
\log{A}
```

(line 3 of your code) and

```
\logA
```

(line 4 of your code), but they're both wrong and it should be `\log A` in both cases.

Actually, `\log{A}` and `\log A` produce the same output, but it wouldn't be the same for `\log{(A+B)` and `\log (A+B)` (check it).

You should use `amsmath` and input your equation as

```
\begin{equation}
S =
\begin{cases}
  1280Q^{0.46}(1.43-0.26\log A) & \text{if $Q<2\,\mathrm{in}$} \\ 
  1958e^{-0.055}Q(1.43-0.26\log A) & \text{if $Q\geq 2\,\mathrm{in}$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

(in mathematics, multiplication is very rarely denoted by an asterisk).

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
S =
\begin{cases}
  1280Q^{0.46}(1.43-0.26\log A) & \text{if $Q<2\,\mathrm{in}$} \\
  1958e^{-0.055}Q(1.43-0.26\log A) & \text{if $Q\geq 2\,\mathrm{in}$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is corrected as you proposed Mr egreg, and now it's good. Thank's for help.